# Archive Utility password

Tags: macos, password, archive-utility

Right when I opened Archive Utility for the first time, it asked me for a password for "activated.info". What password is it talking about and what would I put? I've never used it before so I've never set up a password.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to put passwords on archives as a protection measure.
The password here would be a user-chosen password when compressing the original content to the zipped archive that you're trying to open.

Go back to the source where you downloaded the file and see if there's a password listed somewhere.